# Is there any option to try Google cloud vision api in android app for testing without enabeling billing account

Tags: android, google-cloud-vision

I want to use the vision api in my android app for test is there any option how to do it without enable billing account?

I get this error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "This API method requires billing to be enabled. Please enable billing on project #308443572622 by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/billing/enable?project=308443572622 then retry. If you enabled billing for this project recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
      "reason": "forbidden"
    }
  ],
  "message": "This API method requires billing to be enabled. Please enable billing on project #308443572622 by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/billing/enable?project=308443572622 then retry. If you enabled billing for this project recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable billing just look at the remaining funds in order get it free.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Quickstart: Using Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart-client-libraries) and the error message you get, it is not possible that you can use the Cloud Vision API service without enabling billing for the cloud project. However, you can monitor your usage quota to be below the free quota per [Cloud Vision API pricing](https://cloud.google.com/vision/#pricing-summary) to avoid any charges for your testing purpose.